# An example of $f$ and $a$ such that $f$ is Gâteaux but not Fréchet differentiable at $a$

Tags: derivatives, examples-counterexamples, frechet-derivative, gateaux-derivative

I'm reading [this](http://users.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/AnConvessa/differentiability.pdf) lecture note about differentiability.

---

Let $(X, |\cdot|_X)$ and $(Y, |\cdot|_Y)$ be normed spaces. Let $A$ be an open subset of $X$ and $f: A \to Y$. The directional derivative $f^{\prime}(a) (v)$ of $f$ at $a \in A$ along direction $v \in X$ is the limit (if exists)
$$
f^{\prime}(a)(v) :=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t}.
$$

We shall say that $f$ is:

- *Gâteaux differentiable* at $a$ if there exists $x^{*} \in X^{*}$ such that $f^{\prime}(a)(v)=x^{*}(v)$ for each $v \in X$ (that is, $f^{\prime}(a)$ is everywhere defined, real-valued, linear and continuous); Then $x^{*}$ is called the *Gâteaux differential* (or *derivative*) of $f$ at $a$, and is denoted by $d f(a)$.
- *Fréchet differentiable* at $a$ if there exists $x^{*} \in X^{*}$ such that
  $$
  \lim _{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-x^{*}(h)}{|h|_X}=0 .
  $$
  Then $x^{*}$ is called the *Fréchet differential* (or *derivative*) of $f$ at $a$, and is denoted by $\partial f(a)$.

> Could you provide an example of $f$ and $a$ such that $f$ is Gâteaux but not Fréchet differentiable at $a$?

I only find an [example](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gateaux_derivative#Linearity_and_continuity) in which $f^{\prime}(a)$ exists and is continuous, but not linear.

> For example, consider the real-valued function $F$ of two real variables defined by
> $$
> F(x, y)= \begin{cases}\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & \text { if }(x, y) \neq(0,0), \\ 0 & \text { if }(x, y)=(0,0).\end{cases}
> $$
> Then
> $$
> d F(0,0) (a, b)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> \frac{F(\tau a, \tau b)-0}{\tau} & \text{if } (a, b) \neq(0,0), \\
> 0 & \text{if } (a, b)=(0,0).
> \end{array}= \begin{cases}\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2} & \text{if }  (a, b) \neq(0,0), \\
> 0 &\text{if } (a, b)=(0,0).\end{cases}\right.
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found two examples from [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Relation_to_the_Gateaux_derivative) Wikipedia page.

---

1. In another situation, the function $f$ given by
   $$
   f(x, y)= \begin{cases}\frac{x^3 y}{x^6+y^2} & (x, y) \neq(0,0) \\ 0 & (x, y)=(0,0)\end{cases}
   $$
   is Gateaux differentiable at $(0,0)$, with its derivative there being $g(a, b)=0$ for all $(a, b)$, which is a linear operator. However, $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ (one can see by approaching the origin along the curve $\left(t, t^3\right)$ ) and therefore $f$ cannot be Fréchet differentiable at the origin.
2. A more subtle example is
   $$
   f(x, y)= \begin{cases}\frac{x^2 y}{x^4+y^2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} & (x, y) \neq(0,0) \\ 0 & (x, y)=(0,0)\end{cases}
   $$
   which is a continuous function that is Gateaux differentiable at $(0,0)$, with its derivative at this point being $g(a, b)=0$ there, which is again linear. However, $f$ is not Fréchet differentiable. If it were, its Fréchet derivative would coincide with its Gateaux derivative, and hence would be the zero operator $A=0$; hence the limit
   $$
   \lim _{\|h\|_2 \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f((0,0)+h)-f(0,0)-A h|}{\|h\|_2}=\lim _{h=(x, y) \rightarrow(0,0)}\left|\frac{x^2 y}{x^4+y^2}\right|
   $$
   would have to be zero, whereas approaching the origin along the curve $\left(t, t^2\right)$ shows that this limit does not exist.